# Getting Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:7.0}infinispan' encountered

Tags: java, infinispan

I have the following infinispan xml and getting the parse exception.
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,36]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:7.0}infinispan' encountered

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:7.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd"
xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:7.0">
<jgroups>
  <stack-file name="tcp" path="jgroups-tcp.xml"/>
</jgroups>

<cache-container name="SampleCacheManager" statistics="true" default-cache="the-default-cache" shutdown-hook="DEFAULT">
    <transport stack="tcp" cluster="infinispan-cluster" node-name="Node-A" machine="m1" rack="r1" site="LON" />

    <distributed-cache name="authCache" l1-lifespan="1800000" owners="2" mode="SYNC"  >
        <eviction max-entries="5000" strategy="FIFO" />
        <expiration interval="500"  max-idle="1800000" />
        <persistence passivation="false">

            <file-store path="/opt/UAT_01/cacheStore/" shared="false" preload="true" purge="true">

                <write-behind flush-lock-timeout="5000" modification-queue-size="200" shutdown-timeout="1000" thread-pool-size="15" />
             </file-store>
        </persistence>
    </distributed-cache>

</cache-container>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: What version of Infinispan do you use with this config file?

Comment: I use the 7.0, I have the following in my POM
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
   <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: I had the same problem using an older Infinispan version (4.2).
To fix it, I set the system property `infinispan.config.validate` to `false`. 
To did it, I edited the Wildfly's `standalone.sh` file, doing:
`SERVER_OPTS="-Dinfinispan.config.validate=false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out I was having old jars of infinispan in my lib path. During run time it was higher in the hierarchy and it was getting picked up first. After cleaning it up, it started working like a charm.