# RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entry>

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, infinispan

While migrating infinispan based Cache Application from jboss-5.1.0.GA to jboss-eap-7.0.4

```
2017.03.06 05:33:38 DEBUG CacheContextListener(51): cache instance 

    starting...
2017.03.06 05:33:38 DEBUG InfinispanConfiguration(330): Using schema schema/infinispan-config-4.2.xsd
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71): java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entry>
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:264)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:282)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:136)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:243)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:229)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71): Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entr
y>
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:743)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:105)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleMapNodeProperty$1.childElement(SingleMapNodeProperty.java:197)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:573)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:555)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.config.parsing.NamespaceFilter.startElement(NamespaceFilter.java:29)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:498)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:275)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1198)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory.parse(__XMLReaderFactory.java:176)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:119)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:102)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:256)
2017.03.06 05:33:38 ERROR stderr(71):   ... 17 more
05:33:38,726 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./TestCache: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./TestCache: java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entry>
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property
"). Expected elements are <{}entry>
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:231)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
Caused by:  java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{
}entry>

        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entry>
        at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:264)
        at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:282)
        at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:136)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:243)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:229)

        ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:infinispan:config:4.2", local:"property"). Expected elements are <{}entry>
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:743)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:105)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleMapNodeProperty$1.childElement(SingleMapNodeProperty.java:197)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:555)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.startElement(XMLFilterImpl.java:551)
        at org.infinispan.config.parsing.NamespaceFilter.startElement(NamespaceFilter.java:29)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:498)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:275)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1198)
        at __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory.parse(__XMLReaderFactory.java:176)
        at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:357)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:119)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:102)
        at org.infinispan.config.InfinispanConfiguration.newInfinispanConfiguration(InfinispanConfiguration.java:256)
```

infinispan-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:4.2 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-4.2.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:4.2">

    <global>
        <transport clusterName="${rv.cache.clusterName}">
            <properties>
                <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups-tcp.xml" />
            </properties>
        </transport>
    </global>

    <default>
        <locking isolationLevel="READ_COMMITTED"
            lockAcquisitionTimeout="10000" writeSkewCheck="false"
            concurrencyLevel="50" useLockStriping="false" />
        <clustering mode="replication">
            <stateRetrieval initialRetryWaitTime="1000" timeout="10000" numRetries="10"
                            alwaysProvideInMemoryState="true" fetchInMemoryState="true" />            
            <sync />
        </clustering>
    </default>

</infinispan>
```

Is the error really pointing to some

1) properties file slippages :java.io.IOException

2) Or is it compiling (JDK 1.6) and runtime (JBoss 7 jre 8 ) 
as in 
[Getting Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:7.0}infinispan' encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302110/getting-unexpected-element-urninfinispanconfig7-0infinispan-encountered)

3)Or An Open bug https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-968

Background:
infinispancore.jar is present in the webcontent lib directory.

On excluding the infinispan subsystem in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml getting urn:infinispan:config:4.2

By not packaging in the webcontent, we get noclassdeffounderror but the intention is to retain the WAR packaging as is and exclude the infinispan from the Jboss subsystem

Comment: Do you have env-entry-value for the uri !  Reference : https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ENC_Usage_Conventions-Environment_Entries.html

Answer (score 2):

EAP 7 uses Infinispan 8, so that configuration file is woefully out of date. You need to update it to a newer version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan>
    <jgroups>
        <stack-file name="tcp" path="jgroups-tcp.xml"/>
    </jgroups>
    <cache-container default-cache="default">
        <transport cluster="${rv.cache.clusterName}" stack="tcp" />
        <replicated-cache name="default">
            <locking acquire-timeout="10000" concurrency-level="50" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" striping="false"/>
        </replicated-cache>
</infinispan>
```

Answer (score 1):

apologies for delayed response. The answer shared by Tristan is right but its needs efforts in upgrading the code base. As a workaround Feel I was able to overcome the issue by excluding the below two modules javax.xml.bind.api
and com.sun.xml.bind in Jboss-deployment-structure.xml and add jaxb-api-2.1 , com.springsource.com.sun.xml.bind-2.2.0 in Webcontent directory of the deployed war

Answer (score 0):

To workaround it, I set the system property `infinispan.config.validate` to `false`.
I did it editing Wildfly's `standalone.sh` file, doing:
`SERVER_OPTS="-Dinfinispan.config.validate=false"`